# WordPress on OpenLiteSpeed - able to access website links both via IP (unsecured) and via the domain

Tags: wordpress, redirect, url-rewriting, openlitespeed

I have installed WordPress on OpenLiteSpeed and installed Let's Encrypt for my domain with the option to redirect everything to HTTPS.

My issue is as follows: I am able to access the website's pages, `https://example.com/contact/` for example, also via `http://SERVER_IP_HERE/contact/`

For illlustrative purposes, let's take `161.35.150.160` as my server's IP address.

This shouldn't be possible, right? When someone types `http://161.35.150.160/about/` it should automatically redirect to `https://example.com/about/` and the same should count for any other path requested.

This always was the case with any of my other wp installations, but for some reason I can't get it to work on this site.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^161.35.150.160$ [OR]
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I added these lines to my WordPress directory's `.htaccess` file under, but that didn't do anything. What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: Is your web server Apache?  What is your virtual host configuration in your web server?  If you have full control over your server, you should solve this by adding virtual hosts and not using `.htaccess`.

Comment: It's running on NGINX

Comment: nginx doesn't support `.htaccess` files.  You will need to implement nginx specific configuration.

Comment: Also not via WordPress?